# How to get started reverse engineering SpaceNavigator peripheral data stream?

Tags: java, linux, 3d, protocols, reverse-engineering

I'm playing around with JavaFX 3D, and I have [this 3Dconnexion peripheral](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacemouse/spacenavigator-for-notebooks.html) that's been sitting in a drawer unused for at least a year, and I want to capture its input in Java.

When I plug it in I see a new file: /dev/hidraw2

I can [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) that file and see a bunch of binary gobbledeegook every time I touch the device. For example:

```
hexdump < /dev/hidraw2
0000000 0103 0300 0000 0103 0300 0000 0103 0300
0000010 0000 0001 0000 0100 0200 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0001 0000 0900 0200 0000 0000 0000 0001
0000030 0000 1400 0200 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
```

This input started with three left clicks, and I can clearly see a repeating sequence of bytes there. Then I touched the 3D sensor and things get pretty murky. Other than hexdump, what are the tools of the craft that might help me figure out how to parse this?

By the way, I started by searching for Java spacenav libraries but did not find anything that works.

**update:** This is the output from a single tap on the top of the SpaceNavigator.

```
01 f8  ff 14  00 55  00 02  00 00  15 00  00 00  01 00
00 b0  ff 04  00 02  a5 ff  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00
00 4b  00 02  65 00  fe ff  00 00  01 00  00 bd  ff 00
00 02  d7 ff  08 00  00 00  01 00  00 1e  00 cd  ff 02
37 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 f1  ff 00  00 02  b8 ff
00 00  00 00  01 00  00 2b  00 14  00 02  26 00  00 00
00 00  01 00  00 f5  ff 00  00 02  d1 ff  00 00  00 00
01 00  00 19  00 f5  ff 02  2b 00  00 00  00 00  01 00
00 eb  ff 00  00 02  d9 ff  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 04
00 00  00 02  23 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 fe  ff 00
00 02  f3 ff  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02
09 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  ef ff
00 00  00 00  01 00  00 03  00 00  00 02  08 00  00 00
00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  f5 ff  00 00  00 00
01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  07 00  00 00  00 00  01 00
00 00  00 00  00 02  f7 ff  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00
00 00  00 02  07 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00
00 02  f8 ff  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02
05 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  fc ff
00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  00 00  00 00
00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  00 00  00 00  00 00
01 00  00 00  00 00  00 02  00 00  00 00  00 00  01 00
00 00  00 00  00 02  00 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00
00 00  00 02  00 00  00 00  00 00  01 00  00 00  00 00
00 02  00 00  00 00  00 00
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?Check which Buttons where pressed or ... ?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus I want to capture X, Y, and Z rotation, and X, Y, and Z translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything became much more obvious when I stumbled on the right byte length for a data frame, which was seven. This hexdump command clearly displays an incoming event on each line:

```
hexdump -v -e '7/1 "%02x "' -e '"\n"' </dev/hidraw2
```

The code I wrote to parse the stream is up [on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/travisfw/hidspace/src/de865945177efcd8858387fd8e45035ac74dd2ef/src/main/java/com/traviswellman/hidspace/HidSpaceInputStream.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#HidSpaceInputStream.java-74)

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded their SDK? As far as I remember they have direct support for reading all these values from their API via Java.

Comment: I haven't yet been able to get anything to work. The newest Linux download is from 2005.

Comment: I just stumbled over this older article. http://fxexperience.com/2013/05/3d-spacenavigator-with-javafx/ Maybe there is something in there that helps.